# Camera prompt and camera light is on for audio-only call

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I'm using OpenTok for audio-only calls. When I view the site on Chrome, I get a prompt asking for both camera and microphone permissions, even though I'm only using the microphone. Also, my camera light turns on even though it's an audio-only call. Is there any way I can fix these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not let developers change the words "camera and microphone". As for the light, if you are using a built-in camera and microphone, the camera will turn on, because that is how your laptop signals that you're using the built-in microphone. If you have an external microphone, then the camera light will not turn on.

Comment: Have you considered updating OpenTok to use "getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true}, ...)", which yields the message "http://foo wants to access your microphone" in Chrome.